# Why can't I get edit_bones data?

Tags: bones

I Have a human mesh and corresponding bone
[image]

Then I change it to Edit Mode and hope to modify the position of bones. But when I use rig.data.edit_bones, it gets nothing.
[image]

How can I get edit_bones data and modify its head and tail position? Hoping someone can solve my confusing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your active object before switching to Edit Mode was you mesh object, so you went into that object's Edit Mode, which is a mesh edit mode.

Make you armature object the active one either by <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> or using python:

```py
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['rig']
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer~And can I ask what's the difference between rig.data.bones and rig.data.edit_bones? It seems that for some data bone.head/tail and edit_bone.head/tail is not the same.

Comment: Looking from [ArmatureBones(bpy_struct) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ArmatureBones.html#bpy.types.ArmatureBones) and [ArmatureEditBones(bpy_struct) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ArmatureEditBones.html#bpy.types.ArmatureEditBones), it looks like edit_bones is meant to edit bones, it has functions to create and delete bones.